# How to implement Windows Azure or other cloud platform in my app?

Tags: azure, cloud

I've made a simple productivity app for Windows store 8 and the most requested feature by the reviewers was cloud syncing. I've tried finding some tutorials on how to implement that but haven't found anything useful.

Do I have to use Windows Azure for Windows store 8 apps, because from what I've read it only gives a 3-month trial and It's not worth paying because my app is free with no source of income.

Are there any other cloud computing platforms that are easy to integrate in an app and free ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually every cloud provider would charge you for using their services and even under free mode, they will provide services with certain caveats. For example, Windows Azure Websites are currently free for 1 year when running under shared mode. Amazon AWS provides a free usage tier (http://aws.amazon.com/free/) but it also has some limitation and the moment you go above those, you will be charged.

Not knowing much about your application, there're three possible solution I could recommend (just thinking out loud :):

1. Keep a free version of the product with no cloud syncing (as you have currently).
2. Provide a **ad supported free version** of the product with cloud syncing(kind of freemium offering).
3. Provide a **paid, ad-free version** of the product with cloud syncing.

Answer (score 2):

[SkyDrive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/skydrive/download) (officially Microsoft SkyDrive, previously Windows Live SkyDrive and Windows Live Folders) is a file hosting service that allows users to upload and sync files to a cloud storage.

It gives 7 GB of free cloud storage that's accessible from anywhere.